# How can I move my fcolorbox underneath a description list label?

Tags: positioning, boxes, description

I have a description list. In this list, I have the label name, which should have a score underneath (say in a box with a colored background). Then next to it should be the description. So far, I have been able to properly align things and make the colored score box. However, I do not know how I can move this box so it shows under the label. What is the right way to do this? Here is a MWE and screenshot of desired outcome:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm]

\item[First item]
\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\LARGE 2}
Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
time.

\item[Second item]
\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\LARGE 8}
Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
time.

\item[Third item]
\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\LARGE 6-10}
Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
time.

\item[And here is the fourth] 
\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\LARGE 4}
Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
time.


\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: Showing preferred placement]

Comment: `\item[First item\\
\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\LARGE 2}]` perhaps, with some additional vertical spacing?

Comment: Some remark: Since you use `fcolorbox` with both content and frame colour set to the same colour you could use `\colorbox{colour}{content}` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick trial, needs improvement...

The `\item[...]` allows for a line break in its optional argument, so this a possibility to place the colored box after a line break in this argument.

Below is also an example with the many features of `tcolorbox` instead of `fcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[usenames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}



\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm]

\item[First item\\
\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\LARGE 2}]
Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
time.

\item[Second item\\
\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\LARGE 8}]
Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
time.

\item[Third item\\
\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\LARGE 6-10}]
Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
time.

\item[And here is the fourth\\
\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\LARGE 4}]
Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
time.


\end{description}

\tcbset{colback=orange,width=0.05\labelwidth,left=2pt,right=2pt,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc}

\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm]

\item[{First item\\[0.8ex]
\tcbox{%
\centering
\LARGE 2
}}
]%
Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
time.


\end{description}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I need to figure out what happens with the placement as hspace and vspace don't seem to work out, but it makes more sense to add a separate question for that.

Comment: @user: What's the specific problem?

Comment: Well I try to give the number some padding (say 1cm from the top and 1cm from the left), but vspace and hspace don't seem to do anything!

Comment: @user: Inside the coloured box or outside?

Comment: I want the whole color box to move so I put it after the linebreak and before the colorbox begins.

Comment: @user: I'll try to modify my 'solution'

Comment: Great, much appreciated! In any way I may post another question about positioning because I still wonder why this doesn't work and it is useful to learn it as well...

Comment: @user: I think, one source of the issue is the `multiline` option

Comment: I put the other question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227971/moving-a-colorbox-down-and-right-not-working-with-vspace-and-hspace