# Moving a colorbox down and right not working with vspace and hspace

Tags: spacing, positioning

I have trouble positioning a box and am not sure why this is happening. First, the expected behavior. I want the box to appear 1cm left and 1cm down from my text, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[usenames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

Here is some text, and a box should appear 1cm underneath, 1cm from the left:

  \vspace{1cm}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \colorbox{orange}{\LARGE 6-10}

\end{document}
```

[image: Box down and left]

However, I now want the same within a label of a description list, but very weird things happen.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[usenames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm]
  \item[Third item\\
  %\vspace{1cm} -- These I rotatively turn on and off
  %\hspace{1cm} -- These I rotatively turn on and off
  \colorbox{orange}{\LARGE 6-10}]
  Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
  these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
  We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
  description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
  a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
  information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
  time.

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks WITHOUT any hspace and vspace:

[image: No space]

1cm vspace (???):

[image: 1cm vspace]

1cm hspace (nothing happens):

[image: 1cm hspace]

1cm hspace AND 1cm vspace:

[image: both]

I am a LaTeX beginner and I continue to struggle positioning boxes. I am therefore interested in the solution, but also very much would like to know a) *why* is this happening, b) and how could I find this out myself?

Comment: As a said in a comment to your other question: `multiline` is most probably the cause of the issue, as it alignes `parleft`

Comment: I'm reading up on it now... is there a way around this?

Comment: Where do you want to align the box? right align it?

Comment: @user: I don't know actually

Comment: I want to have the box 1cm below the label, and 1cm from the left, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `\hspace*` rather than `\hspace` to avoid space being dropped at start of line, and you can add vertical space with `\\[1cm]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[usenames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm]
  \item[{Third item\\[1cm]%
  \hspace*{1cm}%
  \colorbox{orange}{\LARGE 6-10}}]
  Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
  these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
  We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
  description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
  a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
  information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
  time.

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a white colored box of `1cm X 1cm` as a workaround:

```
\item[Third item\\
  \textcolor{white}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}%  <--- % needed here
  \colorbox{orange}{\LARGE 6-10}]
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[usenames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm]
  \item[Third item\\
  \textcolor{white}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}%  <--- % needed here
  \colorbox{orange}{\LARGE 6-10}]
  Here is information. This is a multiline description. We will copy
  these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline description.
  We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is a multiline
  description. We will copy these lines a few times. Here is information. This is
  a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few times.Here is
  information. This is a multiline description. We will copy these lines a few
  time.

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was my idea too, but what if the background is not white? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't think the background will not be white.

Comment: ;-) (And some filling) ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Given that you indicate that this is a workaround I'll accept the other answer, but thanks for this option!